# How to set an argument to run a class file using QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I was wondering if there is a way to use `QProcess` to start the main.cpp of another class to enter into its execution as such

```
QProcess *myProcessA = new QProcess();
myProcessA->start("*Anotherclass*main.cpp");
```

I can start applications and other executable arguments via `QProcess`, but the reason is I am integrating an external application (not written in C++) into a widget in Qt.

I can launch the external app via `QProcess` fine, but to embed it I need to launch it in another main thread that would hold the process I already created and sync them.

Sounds confusing but please my question is just plain and simple:

```
QProcess *myProcessA = new QProcess();
myProcessA->start("*Anotherclass*main.cpp");
```

Or better still, how to set an argument/path to run a class file using `QProcess`?

Comment: You cannot run source code, you must compile it to create a separate program, then launch the executable...

Comment: @cbuchart ^ thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run C++ source code using `QProcess`, in a similar way that you cannot run it from a shell or file explorer. You must compile it first to create a separate program. Once compiled, launch the executable created using [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details) similarly as how you've been doing:

```
QProcess *myProcessA = new QProcess();
myProcessA->start("the_exec.exe"); // extension assuming Windows
```